# What's the most idomatic Vue way of handling this higher-order component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a VueJS organization and architecture question. I have a bunch of pages that serve as CRUD pages for individual objects in my system. They share a lot of code . I've abstracted this away in a shared component but I don't love what I did and I'm looking for advice on the idiomatic Vue way to do this.

I'm trying to create a higher order component that accepts two arguments:

1. An edit component that is the editable view of each object. So you can think of it as a stand in for a text input with a v-model accept that it has tons of different inputs.
2. A list component which displays a list of all the objects for that type in the system. It controls navigation to edit that object.

Normally this would be simply something where I use slots and invoke this component in the view page for each CRUD object. So basically I'd have something like this:

```
<!-- this file is src/views/DogsCRUDPage.vue -->
<template>
  <general-crud-component
    name="dogs"
    backendurl="/dogs/"
  >
    <template slot="list">
      <dogs-list-component />
    </template>
    <template slot="edit">
      <dogs-edit-field v-model="... oops .." />
    </template>
 </general-crud-component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "DogCRUDPage",
  components: {
    GeneralCrudComponent,
    DogListComponent,
    DogEditField,
  },  
}
</script>
```

This is nice because it matches the general syntax of all of my other VueJS pages and how I pass props and things to shared code. However, the problem is that GeneralCRUDComponent handles all of the mechanisms for checking if an object is edited, and therefor hiding or unhiding the save button, etc. Therefor it has the editable object in its data which will become the v-model for DogsEditField or any other that's passed to it. So it needs to pass this component a prop. So what I've done this:

```
// This file is src/utils/crud.js

import Vue from "vue"

const crudView = (listComponent, editComponent) => {
  return Vue.component('CrudView', {
    template: `
  <v-row>
    <list-component />
    <v-form>
      <edit-component v-model="obj" />
    </v-form>
  </v-row>
    `,
    components: {
      ListComponent: listComponent,
      EditComponent: editComponent,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        obj: {},
      }
    },
  })
}

export default crudView
```

This file has a ton of shared code not shown that is doing the nuts and bolts of editing, undo, saving, etc.

And then in my src/router/index.js

```
//import DogCRUDPage from "@/views/libs/DogCRUDPage"
import crudView from "@/utils/crud"
import DogListComponent from "@/components/DogListComponent"
import DogEditField from "@/components/design/DogEditField"

const DogCRUDPage = crudView(DesignBasisList, DesignBasis)

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/dog",
      name: "dog",
      component: DogCRUDPage,
    },
})
```

This is working, but there are issues I don't love about it. For one, I needed to enable runtimecompiler for my project which increases the size of the payload to the browser. I need to import the list and edit components to my router instead of just the page for every single object I have a page for. The syntax for this new shared component is totally different from the template syntax all the other pages use. It puts all of my page creation into the router/index.js file instead of just layed out as files in src/views which I am used to in Vue.

What is the idiomatic way to accomplish this? Am I on the right track here? I'm happy to do this, it's working, if this really is how we do this in Vue. But I would love to explore alternatives if the Vue community does something differently. I guess I'm mostly looking for the idiomatic Vue way to accomplish this. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

DogsPage.vue

```
<template>
    <CrudView 
        :editComponent="DogsEdit" 
        :listComponent="DogsList"
    ></CrudView>
</template>

<script>
import DogsEdit from '@/components/DogsEdit.vue'
import DogsList from '@/components/DogsList.vue'
import CrudView from '@/components/CrudView.vue'

export default {
    components: { CrudView },

    data() {
        return { DogsEdit, DogsList }
    }
}
</script>
```

CrudView.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <component :is="listComponent"></component>
      <component :is="editComponent" v-model="obj"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        editComponent: Object,
        listComponent: Object
    },

    data() {
        return {
            obj: {}
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works quite well, thank you. I didn't know about dynamic components.